# Unity play pause audio not working well

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I cannot figure out the right code for playing and pausing the audio source in a single button click.

Here is my Code

```
ButtonAction.GetComponent().onClick.AddListener(delegate
                     {
                         if (soundTarget.isPlaying)
                         {
                             soundTarget.Pause();
                         }
                         else if(!soundTarget.isPlaying)
                         {
                             soundTarget.Play();
                             playSound("sounds/English");
                         }
                     });
```

Note: By default it is not playing because if I play it by default it will just loop around. It is somehow working but I need to click the button multiple times before it plays or pauses.

Help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple :

Your Unity scene should be something like this :

[image]

For the script that I called "UnityUI" is like below :

```
public AudioSource MyAudioSource;
public Button PlayBtn;
public PlayButtonText;

void Start()
{
    PlayBtn.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        if (MyAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            MyAudioSource.Stop();
            PlayButtonText.text = "Play me!";
        }
        else
        {
            MyAudioSource.Play();
            PlayButtonText.text = "Stop me!";
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that this helped!

Happy coding!

Comment: yes that will work if by default it is not playing a sound but what i need is when I click the Playbtn it should play and if i click it again it should pause and so on.

Comment: Your code doesn't work well after I added the AudioSource.Play() at the top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

My code is supposed to be like this. When the button is clicked it will play the sound and when clicked again it will be paused.

```
                            playSound("sounds/English");
                            soundTarget.Play();

                        if (soundTarget.isPlaying)
                        {
                            soundTarget.Stop();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            soundTarget.Play();

                        }
 But this code is just looping around and doesn't play the sound.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update()
    {
            StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();
            IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> tbs = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();

            foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in tbs)
            {
                string name = tb.TrackableName;
                ImageTarget it = tb.Trackable as ImageTarget;
                Vector2 size = it.GetSize();

                Debug.Log("Active image target:" + name + "  -size: " + size.x + ", " 
                + size.y);

                ButtonAction.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                TextDescription.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                PanelDescription.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                ButtonMute.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                if (name == "quezon")
                {
                    ButtonAction.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate
                    {
                        if (soundTarget.isPlaying)
                        {
                            soundTarget.Pause();
                            btn.image.overrideSprite = Play;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            btn.image.overrideSprite = Pause;
                            playSound("sounds/English");
                            soundTarget.Play();
                        }
                    });

                TextDescription.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Manuel L. Quezon was 
                born on August 19, 1878, and died on August 1, 1944. He was a 
                Filipino statesman, soldier, and politician who served as president 
                of the Commonwealth of the Philippines from 1935 to 1944.";
                Narrator.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                void playSound(string ss)
                     {
                       clipTarget = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(ss);
                       soundTarget.clip = clipTarget;
                       soundTarget.loop = false;
                       soundTarget.playOnAwake = false;     
                       soundTarget.ignoreListenerPause = true;
                     }
```

Comment: this code is somehow working but i need to click the button multiple times to play and pause.